# Automatic conversion of winmd to DLL

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'd like to create a tool that accepts a .`winmd` file (Windows Runtime Component) and generates a C# DLL out of it (containing all the public types defined in the component).

As far as I've learned, standard .NET Reflection APIs cannot work on .winmd files, and one must used the [Metadata Unmanaged APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404384.aspx) to access that information.

The question is -- is it possible to construct a C# assembly out of the information that is retrieved from the Metadata API?

Or better yet -- is there a tool (like TLBIMP) that already does this job or something similar?

Comment: Just use a decent disassembler.  Decompiling to C# works fine on Reflector.  Add the .winmd file, also add Windows.winmd.  Right-click + Export Source Code.

Comment: Of course there won't be any code in that winmd file since winmd files are metadata only, but you might be able to see the method definitions that you'd get via intellisense.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That might help change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A windows metadata file doesn't contain any code - it's just a set of type definitions.  And a winmd file is an ECMA 335 assembly, so it already *is* a C# DLL (just rename it from .winmd to .dll).

Comment: That doesn't work. You cannot load a winmd like a normal assembly (getting a NotSupportedException).

Comment: I'll repeat my question from above: What are you trying to do?